# Reference member variable initialization error with default constructor

Tags: c++, reference

I understand that to initialize a reference member variable in a class i have to  use initializers list using a parametrized constructor to initialize the member variable.
Also i understand that there is no need of a default constructor.

**Question:**

1. But what i don't understand is why defining a default constructor throws compilation error?
   Isn't compiler smart enough to consider parametrized constructor in the following case instead of throwing error?
2. If at all there is convincing answer for the above question then why would the compiler allow declaration of default constructor(without definition)? what difference does it make here?

:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    //SomeClass(){} //THIS IS AN ISSUE
    //SomeClass();  //THIS IS FINE THOUGH


    SomeClass(int j):i(j){}
    int& i;

};
int main()
{

    SomeClass obj(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the same is the behavior with const member functions too. Is the reason same for reference and const member variables both?

Comment: You also might want to re-think having a reference member at all - it's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why defining a default constructor throws compilation error?

It's not that you define a default constructor, it's that the default constructor's definition doesn't initialize `i`. You are *required* to initialize all member variables that are references, and your empty definition does not do that.

This is for the same reason that you are required to initialize reference variables:

```
void foo() {
    int &i; // error: declaration of reference variable 'i' requires an initializer
}
```

> why would the compiler allow declaration of default constructor(without definition)

Because the *definition* is the problem, not the declaration.  For example, moving the ill-formed constructor definition outside of the class definition will yield the same error:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    int &i;
};

SomeClass::SomeClass() {} // error: constructor for 'SomeClass' must explicitly initialize the reference member 'i'
```

The only problem with both examples is that you're not initializing `i`.

Take note of the following examples, which will compile.  Note that the constructor's *declaration* does not change, but the *definition* does initialize `i`.

```
int someGlobalInt;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() : i(someGlobalInt) {}
    int &i;
};
```

---

```
int someGlobalInt;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    int &i;
};

SomeClass::SomeClass() : i(someGlobalInt) {}
```

Comment: Well the question is more of : _when i have already provided a way to initialize the member variable through parametrized constructor then why look for default constructor? Moreover in presence of parametrized constructor if definition of a default constructor is not allowed then why should a declaration of default constructor be allowed too? _

Comment: @anurag86 *"in presence of parametrized constructor if definition of a default constructor is not allowed"* -- The definition of a default constructor **is allowed**, you have just provided an ill-formed definition because it doesn't initialize `i`. **You will run into the same errors if you remove your parameterized constructor entirely.**

Answer (score 1):

The compiler requires all references to be initialized. If you define a default constructor that does nothing then the compiler complains because you didn't initialize `i`. If you declare the default constructor you haven't defined it yet so the compiler has no issue. Consider this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    SomeClass(); // Compiler is fine with this
    ...
};

int someInt;
SomeClass::SomeClass(): i(someInt) {} // OK - i is initialized
```

You defined the constructor later and initialized `i`.

Comment: If so then why would even a declaration be allowed?

Comment: @anurag86 why not? You might later want to derive `SomeClass` and use a custom initializer list calling the default ctor of the base class.

Comment: @anurag86 because the compiler only cares about the definition. It can't know whether or not you'll initialize the reference when all it has is the declaration

Answer (score 0):

The first is an implementation of a constructor which fails the required initialisation of the reference member:
`SomeClass(){}`

The second is only a declaration of a constructor. As long as it does not get executed, the lack of implementation is not a problem. And as long as it is not implemented the (probable) failure to initialise is not a problem:
`SomeClass();`

Note that a non-parameterised constructor could initialise a reference member correctly, e.g. to a reference to a global or static variable. That might not be useful for anything, but it is possible. So for the compiler, the second version is no immediate problem and does not necessarily indicate an actual problem elsewhere.